# NodeJs app slows down when i used socket.io for real time updates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, socket.io

I am currently developing a food delivery app using node express and mongoose. I have used socket.io for real time updates of order(to receive the orders in shop side without reloading the page whenever customer orders the food). But the app gets slow when i used socket.io. please suggest the best way to implement it.

**App.js**

```
 mongoose
      .connect(MONGODB_URI, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
      })
      .then((result) => {
        const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
            const io = require("socket.io")(server);
            io.on("connection", (socket) => {
              const changeStream = Order.watch();
              changeStream.on("change", (data) => {
                console.log("changes here " + data); 
                socket.emit("changeData", data.fullDocument);
              });
            });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        res.render("500");
        console.log(err);
      });
```

**order.ejs**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function () {
      var ssid = {
        "id": "<%=sid%>"
      };
      var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
      
      socket.on('changeData', function (msg) {
       
        if (msg != null && msg.shopId == ssid.id) {
              //here i have and appended the data using dom manipulation  
          
          }
   
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
mongoose
  .connect(MONGODB_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  })
  .then((result) => {
    const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
        const io = require("socket.io")(server);
        io.on("connection", (socket) => {
          console.log("connected");
        });
        const changeStream = Order.watch();
          changeStream.on("change", (data) => {
            io.emit("changeData", data.fullDocument);
          });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    res.render("500");
    console.log(err);
  });
```

my problem solved when i emit the event outside connection